# Как правильно отобразить кириллический символ в ajax результате?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, utf-8, кодировка

Из servlet я пишу `out.print("<a href=\"#\">я</a>");`

Когда ajax результирует:

```
   return $.ajax({
             url : options.script,
             type : 'POST',
             dataType : 'HTML',
             data : data
            }).done(function(result) {
             console.log("result: "+ result);
             }
```

Я получаю: `<a href="#" rel="src/?/">?</a>`

Как получить нужный символ `я` вместо `?`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Родной кодировкой для Java является utf-16. Перекодируйте в utf-8.

```
String link = "<a href=\"#\">я</a>";
out.print(link.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```